# Asp.Net application not supporting Non-Ascii characters correctly

Tags: html, asp.net

My .Net application is unable to process some of the Non Ascii characters like '§' etc when reading from the HTML page but a question mark comes in place of that.I have mentioned

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
```

in my Web.config and saved the files in UTF-8 encoding but still it doesn't work.

What could be the reason?Please help

Comment: Can you check value of Content-Type header in HTTP response ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're missing this tag in your views:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

It doesn't matter if you save the HTML pages correctly as UTF-8, you need to specify within the HTML itself that the client browser needs to render the text content as UTF-8.